# Prove by contradiction that if $m^2 - 2m - 3$ is even, then m is odd

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Please help me check if I did it correctly. Honestly I do not understand how to do this. If is wrong please tell me the correct method and explanation. Thanks !

Let $m^2$ be odd and suppose that $m$ is even.

$m = 2p $

$m^2 = (2p)^2 
     = 4p^2 
     = 2(2p^2)
     = 2k$      where $k = 2p^2, k \in ℕ$

This implies that $m^2$ is even.

Therefore, this is a contradiction, and so $m$ is odd.

Comment: Well, it seems incomplete.  I see the argument that $m^2$ odd $\implies m$ odd (which looks fine)  But you never mention the original quadratic.

Comment: Can $m$ be neither odd nor even?

Comment: We consider only integer $m$. Then (0) $2m$ is even. Let (1) $m$ is not odd and (2) $m^2-2m-3$ is even. (1) $\Rightarrow$ (3) $m$ is even. (3) $\Rightarrow$ (4) $m^2$ is even. (0), (4) $\Rightarrow$ (5) $m^2-2m$ is even. (2),(5) $\Rightarrow$ (6) $3$ is even. Contradiction.

Comment: WHy are you letting $m^2$ be odd?  You are *given* that $m^2-2m -3$ is even.  You assume $m$ is not odd and get a contradiction.  So why are you saying things about $m^2$ out of the blue.  ... just start with $m$ is not odd and conclude a contradiction about $m^2 - 2m-3$ being even.  Namely.  If $m$ is not odd then $m$ is even.  Then $m^2=m\times m$ is even, and $2m$ is even, so $m^2 -2m$ is even.  So $m^2 - 2m -3$ is odd... which contradicts $m^2 -2m -3$ being even.

Comment: "This implies that m2

is even.

Therefore, this is a contradiction" That only contradicts your assumption that the $m^2$ is odd which you had no reason to make.  So you have proven that $m^2$ is even.  Which is not a contradiction.  But note.  If $m = 2p$ then $m^2-2m-3 = (2p)^2 + 2(2p) -3 = 4p^2 + 4p -3= 2(2p^2 + 2p-2)-1$ is odd.  ANd that *is* a contradiction of $m^2-2m-3$ being even.

Answer (score 1):

If $m$ is even, then both $m^2$ and $2m$ are even, hence $m^2-2m$ is even, which means that $m^2-2m-3$ is odd.

Comment: Actually, this is proof by contrapositive, if you remove the last word.

Answer (score 0):

$$m^2-2m-3=(m-3)(m+1)$$

If $m$ is even, both $(m-3) and (m+1)$ are odd numbers. Then their product $(m-3)(m+1)$ is an odd number. It is a contradiction.